# Could not create type 'umbraco.webservices.documents.documentService'

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I was trying to install CMS for my ASP.NET (Open source Umbraco). After the installation process, when I try to run the website, I get this error: **Could not create type 'umbraco.webservices.documents.documentService'.    E:\Users\Sarin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite20\umbraco\webservices\api\DocumentService.asmx**

Here's the line from default.aspx which is showing this error.

<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="DocumentService.asmx.cs" Class=umbraco.webservices.documents.documentService %>

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try running it as a webapplication instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds a bit like you've downloaded the source code and are trying to build that. If you do not wish to start bugfixing on Umbraco, you should really just install the recommended download from codeplex.

The install procedure is still mostly the same as shown in [the screencast](http://www.cultiv.nl/blog/2010/2/1/screencast-installing-umbraco) I did a few months back.

Comment: i downloaded the recomended package from codeplex, and I'm getting this same error if you try to do a build or run on the website.

Comment: The Umbraco package should be used as a Web Site Project (and should not be built). See this post for how I usually set it up: http://cultiv.nl/blog/2009/6/1/easily-debug-your-custom-umbraco-user-controls-in-visual-studio/

Comment: I am using it as a website project, but the project should still compile without error. This won't pass the compile check on my build server.

Comment: Sorry, Umbraco 4 has never built successfully. I hope I can help make that better in the future, but for now it won't. You can always configure the build server not to build a certain project.

Answer (score 3):

Change your build to "Build Page".

Right click the solution and select "Property Pages".
Click "Build" in the left and change the "Before running startup page:" drop down to "Build Page."